# Are application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data the only 2 special content types treated by the client when sending data to server?

Tags: javascript, http

I used to search and read posts related to this topic but now I am a little bit confused again.

As before, I read many posts but still didn't see any post clearly clarifying how these different content type would affect or maniuplate the client's data, **when the client is sending data to server**.

---

So here's my understanding (assume it's a `POST` method):

1. There are 2 content types are special and treated differently from the rest.
   `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.

   - with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the client's data is encoded (changed) in some ways.
   - with `multipart/form-data`, the client will use something called `boundary` as a delimiter. As a result, the client can send many stuffs all together in a single request with some `boundary` string inserted as delimiters.
2. And for all the other content types specified by the client (`xmlhttp.setRequestHeader`) , e.g. `application/json`, `application/pdf`, `application/image`, `application/octet-stream` blablabla, the client won't change anything but just put the raw (binary) data in the http request body and send it to the server. The server can retrieve the raw data from the http request body and do whatever it wants.

**Is my understanding/classfication correct?**

---

By saying "client", I mean browser mostly.

By saying "server", I mean the server framework or applicaiton.

Because if I understand correctly, the web server e.g. Nginx or Apache won't do anything to the data. They just pass the data to the server-side application connected to them.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 content types are special and treated differently from the rest.

No. Those 2 content types (and `text/plain` which is pointless and you should never use) are supported by HTML forms.

> with application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the client's data is encoded (changed) in some ways.

With a regular HTML form, all the encodings change the data in some way (even if it is `text/plain`s "Make everything be `name=value` and shove a new line between each item).

> with multipart/form-data, the client will use something called boundary as a delimiter.

Yes. `text/plain` uses a new line. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` uses a `&`. Everything has a delimiter. (You just can't tell the delimiter apart of a new line in the data in `text/plain` which is what makes it useless).

> As a result, the client can send many stuffs all together in a single request with some boundary string inserted as delimiters.

The client can send many things with any of those three encodings.

The different is that multipart supports files.

Multipart lets you put headers before the data for each part, so you can include things like filenames and content-types which are *almost* essential for supporting files.

> And for all the other content types specified by the client (xmlhttp.setRequestHeader) , e.g. application/json, application/pdf, application/image, application/octet-stream blablabla, the client won't change anything but just put the raw (binary) data in the http request body and send it to the server.

Explicitly setting a content type has no effect on what the `XMLHttpRequest` object will do with what you pass to `send()`.

If you pass a string, it will not encode that in any way (so you need to encode the data into the string yourself and set the right content-type header for the encoding you picked). If you pass a `FormData` object then it will encode it as multipart. etc.

> Because if I understand correctly, the web server e.g. Nginx or Apache won't do anything to the data. They just pass the data to the server-side application connected to them.

That's generally the case, but somewhat oversimplified. e.g. There may be no distinction between the server and the server-side application if it is written using Express.js running on Node.js.

---

### Summary

- Forms always encode the data. The `enctype` attribute tells them which way to do it.
- `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch` **may** encode the data, but it depends on what kind of value you pass to them. If it is a string, you have to encode it and set the right Content-Type yourself.

Comment: *"Explicitly setting a content type has no effect on what the XMLHttpRequest object will do with what you pass to send()."* . When pass a string to `XMLHttpRequest`,  isn't  specifiying `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header will percent encode some characters while specifying other headers e.g. `application/json` or `application/octet-stream`, the browser won't percent encode the string but keep the string raw?

Comment: @Rick — The string will be kept raw in all three of those cases. Setting a content-type header will not implicitly percent encode data passed to `send`.

Comment: I don't get it. MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`: *" Non-alphanumeric characters in both keys and values are percent encoded: this is the reason why this type is not suitable to use with binary data"*

Comment: @Rick — That describes what correctly formatted `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data is. It **doesn't** say that XMLHttpRequest will encode data using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format when you pass a string to `send()` and set the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Nothing is stopping you from sticking a string of garbage into `send()` and then **lying** in the `Content-Type`.

Comment: Ah I see. MDN is saying that if I pass/submit my data from a  html `<form>`, then the data will be precent encoded.